# An application of Hensel's lemma to some different fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I would like to prove the following. 
Let $p>2$ be a prime number, $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ the field of p-adic numbers
Let $u\in \mathbb{Z}_{p}^{\times}$ be a unit. (1)Prove that the following are equivalent
$$(i) \text{ There exists } b \in \mathbb{Q}_{p} \text{ such that } u = b^2.$$
$$(ii) \text{ There exists }b \in \mathbb{Z}_{p}^{\times} \text{ such that }u = b^2.$$
$$(iii) \text{ There exists }\bar{b} \in \mathbb{F}_{p} \text{ s.th. if } \bar{u} \text{ denotes the reduction of } u \text{ modulo the ideal } p\mathbb{Z}_{p}, \text{ then }\bar{u} = \bar{b}^2.$$

(2) Using the above remark, prove that there exists a unit $u_0 \in \mathbb{Z}_{p}^{x}$ such that, for all $b \in \mathbb{Q}_p, \; u_0 \neq b^2$.

(3) Let $u_0$ be as in (2), let $a \in \mathbb{Q}_p$, and let $K = \mathbb{Q}_{p}(\sqrt{a})$.

Prove that $ K \in \lbrace \mathbb{Q}_p, \mathbb{Q}_{p}(\sqrt{u_{0}}), \mathbb{Q}_{p} (\sqrt{p}),\mathbb{Q}_p (\sqrt{u_{0} p})\rbrace$.

Comment: ii) implies iii) is obvious, iii) implies i) is Hensel's lemma applied to the polynomial $x^2-\bar{u}$ which has 2 distinct roots since $p>2$ and i) implies ii) because if $b=x/y$, with $x,y\in \mathbb Z_p$, then $uy^2=x^2$ holds in $\mathbb Z_p$, which is a UFD...

Comment: I’ve come across this rather late, and I ask: what do you know already, and  what have you tried?

Comment: Well the first question is just Hensel´s lemma. Making sure that you have no division by zero for (i) implies (iii). The second and third question are harder, care to answer?

Comment: For (2),  you just take a nonsquare in $\mathbb F_p$ and lift it any way to an element of $\mathbb Z_p$. You need the cyclicity of $\mathbb F_p$, of course. Use this also to show that the product of two nonsquare units of $\mathbb Z_p$ is a square.